# How to identify elements with same ID, Name etc

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, tags

Here is the HTML code of all the tabs on my page.  I need to go through all of them. I see their tags at the end of each line are different but how to locate them so selenium see them?

```
<div id="Options_tabs" name="Options_tabs" class="BSTabs" style="position:relative;overflow:auto;z-index:100;width:100%;"><div id="Options" name="Options" baseclass="BSTab" class="BSTabOFF" onclick="uiTabSelect(this);"> General </div><div id="Options" name="Options" baseclass="BSTab" class="BSTabON" onclick="uiTabSelect(this);"> Agent Key </div><div id="Options" name="Options" baseclass="BSTab" class="BSTabOFF" onclick="uiTabSelect(this);"> Contact Details </div><div id="Options" name="Options" baseclass="BSTab" class="BSTabOFF" onclick="uiTabSelect(this);"> Invoicing </div><div id="Options" name="Options" baseclass="BSTab" class="BSTabOFF" onclick="uiTabSelect(this);"> Referral </div></div>
```

Comment: Use REGEX to match the lines you need.

Comment: Having several divs with the same id seems wrong . I'm no selenium expert but I'd assume fixing that should allow you to access the tabs by id.

Comment: Use the plural version findElements(By.id("Options")) which will return a list... Iterate through the list and fetch the text...

Comment: None of the above solutions worked

Comment: Can you post what you tried based on @Grasshopper's comment so that we can figure out what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [this tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/accessing-forms-in-webdriver.html#1) . The page has a lucid and easy-to-understand examples. Try following it, it will answer your question hopefully.

Also [this link](https://www.guru99.com/accessing-links-tables-selenium-webdriver.html)- on Accessing Links & Web Tables using Selenium Webdriver.

You can also follow [seleniumeasy.com](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials) . It has extensive examples on Locating elements by Selenium.